# Android Studio: release apk signing process

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signing, build.gradle

I haven't fully understood how the release apk signing process in Android Studio/Gradle works.

I can see, you can specify the release signing details (location/alias/passwords) in two different places:

- in the *gradle.build* configuration file
- in the wizard which is coming up by selecting "*Build/Generate Signed APK*" from the Android Studio top menu

As far as I can understand, these two places don't talk to each other.

**My questions are**:

1) what are the signing details specified in each of these two places for?

2) if I have "*release*" selected on the "build variant" Android Studio vertical tab, and I click on the green triangle button (RUN button) on the top menu, will I be running on my device a release version which is signed? using which signing details?

Comment: If you try sign release from menu in latest Android Studio it warns about that gradle build should have signing specified in build.gradle file. I haven't checked what is going to be next if you continue. But I highly recommend you to follow warning and specify signing for release at least. After this every build variant with release build configuration will be signed with your release keys

Answer (score 3):

> 1) what are the signing details specified in each of these two places
>   for?

Signing configuration in `build.gradle` script files gives you the power of automation of builds. For example, if you want to use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or other build automation tools where you will not have any dialog or interface to enter your signing configuration signed builds will automatically generated with the signing configuration specified by you in build scripts.

In Android Studio the signing configuration which are entered in a dialog from `Build > Generate Signed apk` is limited to your system only. It doesn't add your signing configuration in gradle build scripts and you can not use `Run` tool menu to run directly the signed application in the device by choosing release in Build Variants.

> 2) if I have "release" selected on the "build variant" Android Studio
>   vertical tab, and I click on the green triangle button (RUN button) on
>   the top menu, will I be running on my device a release version which
>   is signed? using which signing details?

The green triangle button (RUN button) on the top menu will not take any configuration specified in the `Build > Generate Signed apk` dialog, It will run the app with signing details specified in build scripts. Yes, running application with green triangle button will install your signed application directly on device but with the signing configuration specified in build scripts. I like this feature very much in AS.